# $2+ f(x)f(y)=f(x)+f(y) +f(xy) $, if $f(2)=5$ find $f(5)$

Tags: proof-verification, functional-equations

This question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270658/fx-is-a-polynomial-satisfying-2-fxfy-fxfyfxy-find-ff2), however I am interested in seeing why my approach to finding a solution does not work.

> $2+ f(x)f(y)=f(x)+f(y) +f(xy) $, if $f(2)=5$ find $f(5)$

What I have done is the following:

Plugging in 0 gives us a quadratic which can be solved to give the values of $f(0)=1, 2$

Now if I take $x=5, y=0$ using $f(0)=1$ gives us $$1=1$$ Which is not useful.

Using $f(0)=2$ we get $f(5)=2$.

---

This is not the correct answer, which is given as $26$.

> Why is this an incorrect method to go about solving the question?

Comment: Taking $x=5, y=0$ with $f(0)=1$ gives $2+f(5)\times 1=f(5)+1+1\implies 2=2$.  No problem.

Comment: Why not include the link to the prior version of the question?

Comment: You just included a link to your own question.   The [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618040/finding-value-of-the-function-fxfy-fx-fy-fxy-2) assumes that $f$ is continuous (actually, polynomial) which, as far as I can tell, is an absolutely essential assumption.

Comment: "Using $f(0)=2$ we get $f(5)=2$."  I'm going to guess that your mistake is in there somewhere, but you've not really shown us what you did (nor in the earlier question).

Comment: "Plugging in $0$", is confusing. Just say letting $x=y=0$. I don't thing you meant $x=5$. Didn't you mean $x=2$?. Also, if part of the question was that $f(x)$ was supposed to be a polynomial, then you could have wasted some of the reader's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What appears to be incorrect in your method is that you seem to be ruling out the possibility that $f(0)=1$ because it leads to a result that is "not useful."  In a logical argument, you can only rule something out if it leads to a contradiction. The conclusion $1=1$, while indeed not useful, is nonetheless *true*. So $f(0)=1$ remains a viable option.

Indeed, as Kavi Rama Murthy's answer shows, it's the possibility $f(0)=2$ that leads to a contradiction: Letting $x=0$ and $y=2$ in the equation $2+f(x)f(y)=f(x)+f(y)+f(xy)$ gives

$$f(0)=2\implies 2+2f(2)=2+f(2)+2\implies f(2)=2\not=5$$

However, knowing now that $f(0)$ must equal $1$ is, as you put it, not useful.  All it says is that $2+f(y)=1+f(y)+1$. But neither is the conclusion $f(1)=2$, which you can derive from $2+f(1)f(2)=f(1)+f(2)+f(1\cdot2)$, because all it'll tell you is that $2+2f(y)=2+f(y)+f(y)$.

In point of fact, *nothing* you do here will prove useful, because the problem, as stated, has dropped an assumption from the question linked to in the OP, namely that the function $f$ be a polynomial. Without an additional assumption on the nature of the function, $f(5)$ can have literally *any* value.

Answer (score 11):

$f(0)=2$ does not lead to  valid solution to the equation. If $f(0)=2$ put $x=0$ to get $2+2f(y)=4+f(y)$ or $f(y)=2$ for all $y$. This is in conflict with the given condition $f(2)=5$ so we cannot take $f(0)=2$.